# bash how to pass variable to the remote bash script

Tags: bash

I have local bash script which is used to invoke a bash script in the remote server and get some reports from remote server.

The way I call this script currently in `local_script.sh` is:

```
ssh remoteuse@ip "/bin/bash remote_script.sh"
```

Now, I want to set a date variable in `local_script.sh` file and variable needs to available in `remote_script.sh` files also.

Please give some ideas.

**EDIT**:

Please see my test script:

`[user@localserver]$ ssh remoteusr@ip "/bin/bash  remote_script.sh  $test_var"`

And my remote script:

```
[user@remoteserver]$ cat remote_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $test_var > test_var.log
```

But `test_var.log` file on remote server is empty after running the script

Comment: I have noticed you commented on other solutions whether they helped or not. Please take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51947802/6176817) as well, any feedback is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The remote server doesn't know you local variables, you can only pass the value of the variable from local to remote with an extra argument at the ssh line:

```
ssh remoteuse@ip "/bin/bash remote_script.sh $variable"
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I tried the same and not working for me. I have added my test script in post. Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the variable to the environment of the executed command. That can be done with the [`var=value cmd` syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion).

But since the line you pass to `ssh` will be evaluated on the remote server, you must ensure the variable is in a **format that is reusable as shell input**. Two ways come to mind depending on your version of `bash`:

1. With `bash 4.4` or newer, you can use the `Q` operator in [`${parameter@operator}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

   **local script:**

   ```
   foo="abc'def  \"123\"  *"
   ssh remoteuse@ip "foo=${foo@Q} /bin/bash remote.sh"
   ```

   **remote script:**

   ```
   printf '<%s>\n' "$foo"
   ```

   **output:**

   ```
   $ ./local_script.sh
   <abc'def  "123"  *>
   ```
2. If you don't have `bash 4.4` or newer, you can use the `%q` directive to `printf`:

   ```
   ssh remoteuse@ip "foo=$(printf '%q' "$foo") /bin/bash remote.sh"
   ```