# Pass variable to subshell created via -c option

Tags: bash, raspbian

I want to pass my variable to subshell process created via `-c` option. I have a install.sh file in which I execute the following lines and expect the printf receives $AUTOSTART_FILE value.

`AUTOSTART_FILE=/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

`sudo sh -c 'printf "@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi\n@/home/pi/exec.sc" > $AUTOSTART_FILE'`

I read and applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946970/bash-how-to-pass-variable-to-the-remote-bash-script) answer with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could export the variable and tell sudo to use it.

```
export AUTOSTART_FILE
sudo -E ....
```

You could serialize the variable and import in sh

```
... sh -c "$(declare -p AUTOSTART_FILE)"'printf %s "$AUTOSTART_FILE"'
```

But the best is to just pass it as an argument:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi\n@/home/pi/exec.sc" > "$1"' -- "$AUTOSTART_FILE"
```

Or really you could just grab a tee:

```
printf "@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi\n@/home/pi/exec.sc" | sudo tee "$AUTOSTART_FILE" >/dev/null
```